# How do I create a path alias and redirect node?

Tags: 8, path-aliases, redirection

I want to create a path alias pattern like `[base_url][title]` and overwrite the existing path alias for a specific content type. Also, all the nodes are redirected to the new custom alias.

e.g., existing alias pattern is A/B/C and the generated url is www.test.com/de/A/B/C - Need to convert into www.test.com/C where de is language code here.

What approach should I take?

Comment: Use the Redirect module

Comment: I do not want to give the access to redirect module to the End-user, need to do programmatically or any other configuration.

Comment: So don’t give them access to it? It’s permission based.

Comment: @latikas, Pathauto can redirect old aliases when generating new ones. But it can't remove a language prefix, because this is handled separately by language detection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, instead of Pathauto module any alternative solution? Using pathauto module, we need to add redirect urls manually.

Comment: With Pathauto + Redirect this should work automatically, check in Redirect settings: "Automatically create redirects when URL aliases are changed."